# How to upload .xml file in IOS app using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my IOS app I have one `abc.xml` file through which I get data and display it on screen (I have already done with that, no issue for doing this), my problem is,on button click I want to upload any .xml file to my app (I have some .xml file in my ipad) and want to replace that `.xml` file with `abc.xml` file,  (then i will fetch data through that newly uploaded file)

It is just like "choose file" option in web

*can we do this in iOS app using Objective-C?*

Comment: Do you want to download a XML file to an iPad? Or upload the XML to Web Server?

Comment: XML file is exists at your project or in ipad device..!. I mean abc.xml is in ipad or within project...!

Comment: yes, right now abc.xml file is within project, but i want to upload any xml file in my ipad device

Answer (score 0):

iOS uses `.plist` setting configuration files. I don't know how well this would work, but you could try something a little like this...

```
NSMutableDictionary *abcDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" fileType:@"xml"]];
NSString *someString = (NSString*)[abcDict valueForKey:@"someString"];
NSNumber *someNumber = (NSNumber*)[abcDict valueForKey:@"someNumber"];
NSDictionary *someDictionary = (NSDictionary*)[abcDict valueForKey:@"someDict"];
NSArray *someArray = (NSArray*)[abcDict valueForKey:@"someArray"];
BOOL *someBoolean = [((NSNumber*)[abcDict valueForKey:@"someBool"]) booleanValue]
```

Just change your code depending on your data type. `BOOL` is a bit weird, but everything else is written just like that. Use the right key names, and if XML doesn't work, try plugging a `.plist` file into your app!

Comment: Thanks, its helpful But my problem is how can i upload any xml file outside of my app , just like "choose file" option in web

Comment: iOS apps don't typically save stuff as `.xml` files. I would add `.xml` to the types of files it can open, and then I'd refer to the developer documentation for the `ApplicationDelegate` and make a method that can interpret said file in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you want, this should make the trick.

```
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:linkURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( urlData )
    {
        BOOL success = [db writeToFile:@"locationOfTheFile" atomically:YES];
        if (success) {
            //all went well
        }else{
            //error
        }

    }
```

edit:
if the file is at the root of your app, you can get the path with this.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

BOOL success = [db writeToFile:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName"];
```

Comment: thanks, what do u mean by url ? my .xml file is not hosted on web space, it is locally on my own ipad

Comment: but where will the the new xml file be?

Comment: in my ipad, not on web